# How to prove this equality about logarithm series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Actually, I have 2 questions. 1) How to prove that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to+\infty}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n} \ln \left( \frac{n}{2k-1} \right) = 1-\ln(2)?$$
2) Are there some nice materials on the topic of how to compute such a series?

Comment: To learn more about limits of this kind, look up [Riemann Sums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$L=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{n} \ln \left ( \frac{1}{2k/n-1/n}\right) =\int _{0}^{1} \ln \frac{1}{2x} dx=  -\ln 2-\int_{0}^{1} \ln x dx= -\ln 2 +1.$$
Note that $1/n$ in the argument of $\ln$ can be neglected when $n\rightarrow \infty.$